# Google Pay button is not displayed on the stripe's payment sheet

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

#### Description

Using `flutter_stripe` package, version `^1.2.0`, to perform payment on the front end, Google pay button wasn't displayed on the paymentSheet despite setting the flag `googlePay: true` in `SetupPaymentSheetParameters` while initializing the payment sheet using `Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet()`.

The [examples project](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/tree/main/example) of the package doesn't provide information about configuring google pay in payment sheet other than setting the flag to true, so i followed these [instructions](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android&ui=payment-sheet#google-pay) form stripe's documentations to integrate google pay but the button still not displayed on the sheet.

#### My Code

- stripe initialization

```dart
    Stripe.publishableKey = dotenv.env['STRIPE_PUB_KEY'];
    Stripe.instance.applySettings();
```

- payment sheet methods

```dart
  Future<void> initializePaymentSheet(
    PaymentCredentials credentials,
  ) async {
    Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
      paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
        applePay: Stripe.instance.isApplePaySupported.value,
        googlePay: true,
        style: ThemeMode.dark,
        testEnv: true,
        merchantCountryCode: 'USA',
        merchantDisplayName: 'Our App. Inc.',
        customerId: credentials.clientId,
        paymentIntentClientSecret: credentials.paymentIntent,
        customerEphemeralKeySecret: credentials.eKey,
        customFlow: false,
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> presentPaymentSheet(String paymentIntent) async =>
      Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet(
        parameters: PresentPaymentSheetParameters(
          clientSecret: paymentIntent,
          confirmPayment: true,
        ),
      );
```

What is missing to display this button on the sheet?

Comment: Read this prerequisite https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay

Comment: It works for me with google pay installed and a credit card added to google pay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Romeo said in the comments above, Google pay button was displayed when gPay app is installed and there is at least one card available on it.
I was using separate google pay button on my app using `pay` plugin and it was displayed along with google pay sheet so i figured it should be shown on stripe's payment sheet as well.